# Remove single item from a list inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

This feel really simple but I tried many scripts and nothing works.
I have an interface with Id field - named `ITrust`,
And I have a dictionary - `Dictionary<string, Ilist<ITrust>>`.
Now I'm trying to remove a single object from the list inside the dictionary but can't find the right script.

I tried some things like that:

```
dictionaryName[keyName].Remove(x => x.Id == Id);
```

But it raise an exception -

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type `ITrust` because it is not a delegate type

Any one know the right script or maybe if there is a problem with might I try to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, that's a compilation error, not an exception. And second, stop using `IList<>` if you don't understand what it means.

If you use a normal `List<>`, you have a [`List.RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-7.0) function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Also, based on the fact that you need this, I very much doubt that a list is the correct data structure for you. You should probably be using a `HashSet<>` instead.

Comment: He seems to use IList not IList<T>.

Comment: @Ralf, I don't believe you, the error message is strongly typed. Do you have any backing evidence to your claim?

Comment: No. Just what he wrote.

Comment: Thanks @Blindy, That did work although I do need IList<T> for testing but I will manage to find a way around it. anyway you helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why they shouldn't use `IList<T>`. Even if `List<T>` is better, the remark is quite condescending.

Comment: @GertArnold: i agree about the remark, but i think `IList<ITrust>` is not the right collection here if he wants to remove items. Because `ITrust[]` would also implement `IList<ITrust>` but cause an exception at runtime because an array cannot be modified. I agree with Blindy that a `ISet<ITrust>` might be best, because it seems that an `Id` is a unique identifier and also because a set is more efficient then.

Comment: That is correct, and is exactly the reason why `IList<>` is the wrong type to use: removing an element from a fixed size array makes no sense.